# Adding a title that includes angle between two vectors in Graphic in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Black,
   Arrow[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, -5}, {0, 5}}],
   Blue,
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowA}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowB}]
   }],
 {{arrowA, {3, 3}}, Locator},
 {{arrowB, {-3, 3}}, Locator},
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, 
    Row["\[Theta] = ", 
     ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/(Norm[arrowA] Norm[arrowB])]]}}
 ]
```

Which produces the following image.

[image]

It doesn't calculate the angle. Any suggestions?

**Due to helpful suggestions:** The suggestions get me to this point.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Black, Arrow[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, -5}, {0, 5}}], 
   Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowA}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowB}]}], {{arrowA, {3, 3}}, 
  Locator}, {{arrowB, {-3, 3}}, Locator}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, 
    Row["\[Theta] = ", 
     Dynamic[N[
       ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/(Norm[arrowA] Norm[arrowB])]/
        Degree]]]}}]
```

[image]

But I just want $\theta=90$, not the Row and the Brackets.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Do `Dynamic@ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/(Norm[arrowA] Norm[arrowB])]`

Comment: `Row[{"\[Theta] = ",  Dynamic[ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/(Norm[arrowA] Norm[arrowB])]]}]`?

Comment: @kguler: Almost. See your idea in my original post above. How do I get rid of the Row and the Brackets?

Comment: As a second question, is it possible to put some code prior to the Graphics block that I could use in the Frame title without the use of Dynamic?

Comment: `Dynamic[Row[{"\[Theta] = ", 
   N[ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/(Norm[arrowA] Norm[arrowB])]/Degree]}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1-st argument given to `Row` must be a list.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    Black, Arrow[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, -5}, {0, 5}}], 
    Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowA}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowB}]}], 
  {{arrowA, {3, 3}}, Locator},
  {{arrowB, {-3, 3}}, Locator}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, 
    Row[{"θ = ", 
      Dynamic[ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/Norm[arrowA]/Norm[arrowB]]/
        N @ Degree], "°"}]}}]
```

[image: graphics]

#### Update

Just a suggestion, but I think the label looks better when the `Row` expression is written to round the angle to the nearest degree.

```
Row[{
  "θ = ", 
  Dynamic[Round[ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/Norm[arrowA]/Norm[arrowB]]/N @ Degree]], 
  "°"}]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: @David, you might be interested to know that `VectorAngle[]` is built-in…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. How do you guys highlight VectorAngle[]. I've often seen this, but don't know how to do it. Think it would be good if I knew how.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I had just tried this:    Row[{"\[Theta] = ", 
  Dynamic[NumberForm[
    ArcCos[(arrowA.arrowB)/Norm[arrowA]/Norm[arrowB]]/N@Degree, {3, 
     1}]], "\[Degree]"}]

Comment: We just enclose them in backticks (`), @David.